# Confusion about Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure for inserting data into my table. These are my table's columns with their datatype:

```
Ad nvarchar(150),
Yazar nvarchar(150),
SayfaSayisi smallint,
KategoriId int
Gmc datetime,
HostName  nvarchar(150)
```

The problem is that `Gmc` and `HostName` have their own default values. So I can't use these two in the stored procedure.

```
Gmc ---> GetDate() (to get insert date)
HostName --> Host_Name(  )
```

So when I execute the query I am getting this error.

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement

This is the query

```
Create proc Kitap_Insert
    @Ad nvarchar(150),
    @Yazar nvarchar(150),
    @SayfaSayisi smallint,
    @KategoriId int
    Gmc datetime,
    HostName nvarchar(150)
as
    Insert into Kitap(Id, Ad, Yazar, SayfaSayisi, KategoriId)
    values(@Ad, @Yazar, @SayfaSayisi, @KategoriId)
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Just don't mention the columns with default values in the INSERT's column list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove `ID` from insert list

```
  Insert into Kitap(Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
     values(@Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```

or add a value for it as below

```
  Insert into Kitap(Id,Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
     values(@ID, @Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
Insert into Kitap(Id,Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
 values(@Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```

Use:

```
INSERT INTO Kitap(Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
VALUES (@Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```

You are asking SQL engine that you will provide id (an additional field) as well (field that doesn't exist in the table or is an auto increment field) and you are not providing the value for the same and hence your error `here are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement`

So remove additional Id from your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting because you tried to insert value into more column names than specified in `Values Clause`.

If you have `ID` column as `Auto-increment` field in table so you dont have to include that `ID` column in so your insert query will be like this:-

```
Insert into Kitap
           (Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
       values
           (@Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```

If you don't have `ID` column as `Auto-increment` field in table so you provide value to that id column also in `Value Clause` so your insert query will be like this:-

**NOTE:-**
You have to calculate and Set Value to @Id variable before using it in `Insert Query`

```
  Declare @Id as INT
  SET @ID = ---- set here with some value which will become Primary key(I think)
  Insert into Kitap
           (Id,Ad,Yazar,SayfaSayisi,KategoriId)
       values
           (@Id, @Ad,@Yazar,@SayfaSayisi,@KategoriId)
```